# problems of keeping armature after put dynotopo on in sculpting mode

Tags: armature, pose-mode

[image]i'm working in Blender 2.81 and making a sculpture where i after been in posemode,go to sculpt mode. When i then activate Dyntopo, then goes my sculpture in rest position,- and all my position is gone, from all my sculpture - se picture 2 . my position is gone from the stack.
Should i aply the armature modifier in object mode.
can i preserve my armature for lather rearangements of position?
If i make copy armature there is coming some problems.

What is the right way to do this ?[![armature in posemode
[[image: ][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx386.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ujN2.jpg)

Comment: Another way is just to re weight paint your mesh to the armatures.

Comment: hey Robert   Do you say that i can take the new more detailed figur, and come it over to fit the armature, - and then using weight paint atache it to the armature? Or just parented it, - with automatic weights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dyntopo messes with vertex groups, and the weights attached to an armature are vertex groups. That means that if you want to sculpt an object that is being posed by an armature, you have two options: either don't use Dyntopo or apply the armature modifier. The latter option is only a good one if you don't plan on changing the pose; if you choose that option, I'd first make a copy of your current object that you can revert to if you change your mind. The other option would be to leave Dyntopo off, and just use subdivisions instead, as long as you're not planning on sculpting small details. In fact, if all you want to do is smooth out the joints, for example, just adding a Subsurf modifier after the armature modifier might do the trick with no sculpting required.

Comment: can i make the copy in armature, under the option copy at the right side, - or is it to make a hole new copy file in another colection ?